# Botão que Carrega mais 3 posts

Tags: wordpress, loop, post

Estou querendo que meu botão `id="boot"` (`<div id="boot">`) a cada vez que seja apertado, carregue +3 depoimentos.

```
<?php 
query_posts( array ( "category_name" => "depo" ));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
<article id="post-28" role="article" style="margin-left:20px;">

<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<h1 class="titulo-depo" ><b><a class="index-tro"href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></b></h1>
<h2 class="depo-p"><b><?=the_content();?></b></h2>

</article>

<?php 

$cont_banner++;
endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?> 
<div id="bott"><a href="eventos.php"><p>+DEPOIMENTOS</p></a></div><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: O que acontece quando você clica nele?

Comment: Eu quero que quando cliqua ele abra +3 post em baixo na parte <h2 class="depo-p"><b><?=the_content();?></b></h2>

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como mostrar mais posts quando clicar em botão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49772/como-mostrar-mais-posts-quando-clicar-em-bot%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar com o WP_Query? E aí você pode fazer a paginação... Aí tem a opção de fazer na mão ou usar o plugin do jetpack para fazer o infinite scroll / botão para carregar mais.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'category_name' => 'depo',
  'posts_per_page'  => 3
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Espero ter ajudado, se eu puder ajudar em mais alguma coisa, só falar =)